# Combine the result of two parallel tasks in one list

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I want to combine the result of 2 tasks in one List collection.

**Make sure that- I want to run both methods in parallel.**

### Code:

```
List<Employee> totalEmployees = new List<Employee>();
```

Method1:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> SearchEmployeeFromDb();
```

Method2:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployeeFromService();
```

Now, I want to hold the result of these two methods in `totalEmployees` field, also these 2 method should run asynchronously.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

While many answers are close, the cleanest and most efficient option is using `Task.WhenAll` combined with `SelectMany`:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> Combine()
{
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(SearchEmployeeFromDb(), GetEmployeeFromService());
    return results.SelectMany(result => result);
}
```

This assumes that by parallel you mean concurrently. If you wish to run these operations with multiple threads from the beginning (including the synchronous parts of the `async` method) you need to also use `Task.Run` to offload work to a `ThreadPool` thread:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> Combine()
{
    var results =
        await Task.WhenAll(Task.Run(() => SearchEmployeeFromDb()), Task.Run(() => GetEmployeeFromService()));
    return results.SelectMany(result => result);
}
```

Comment: Why not add ConfigureAwait(false) to the WhenAll returned task?

Comment: @Cybrosys Why add? (other than the fact that most library grade code should probably have that)

Comment: This code might be in a library or called from another layer asynchronous. Isn't it best practice to always use ConfigureAwait(false) unless you have a specific need to return to the original thread?

Comment: @Cybrosys It's an opinion (which is probably true) for all `async` development but I think it's unrelated to this specific question. Either you add it to all your `async` calls (this one included) or you don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create a task which will return when all supplied tasks are complete

```
var result = await Task.WhenAll(SearchEmployeeFromDb(),GetEmployeeFromService());
var combined = result[0].Concat(result[1]);
```

Comment: I also need to combine the result of both the methods @Jamiec !!

Comment: Task.WhenAll returns a Task object which doesn't have indexer to access the collection.

Comment: @nunu - you're right it should be `tasks.Result[x]` Updated

Comment: @Jamiec When you await the result of `Task.WhenAll` you don't get a task.

Comment: @I3arnon - Im not doing very well on this answer am I?! Is that right now (awaiting gets you the result of the task, right?)

Answer (score 1):

- Start both tasks
- Use `Task.WhenAll` to wait for both tasks to finish
- Use `Enumerable.Concat` to combine the results

```
var searchEmployeesTask = SearchEmployeeFromDb();
var getEmployeesTask = GetEmployeeFromService();

await Task.WhenAll(searchEmployeesTask, getEmployeesTask);

var totalEmployees = searchEmployeesTask.Result.Concat(getEmployeesTask.Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var t1 = SearchEmployeeFromDb()
var t2 = GetEmployeeFromService()

await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2)

// Now use t1.Result and t2.Result to get `totalEmployees`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlocking, define the tasks, execute and then await.

```
var fromDbTask = SearchEmployeeFromDb().ConfigureAwait(false);
var fromServiceTask = GetEmployeeFromService().ConfigureAwait(false);

var fromDbResult = await fromDbTask;
var totalEmployees = new List(fromDbResult);

var fromServiceResult = await fromServiceResult;
totalEmployees.AddRange(fromServiceResult);
```

... or use whichever way you want to merge the two lists.

I updated the solution, it was unneccessary to create the list and then append the first result. We wait for the first method to finish and then create the list.

Comment: awaiting one task at a time is not true asynchronous! I want both the method should run parallel.

Comment: They both execute here:
var fromDbTask = SearchEmployeeFromDb().ConfigureAwait(false);
var fromServiceTask = GetEmployeeFromService().ConfigureAwait(false);

So yes, they do run asynchronous.

Comment: Agree, if they both execute there, then why need to use 'await' statement while assigning it to field?

Comment: The await keyword merely says that if the task is not finished once we reach this point, we wait for the result. It doesn't matter which one of these two finish first because the total time it takes for this method to finish is the same.

Comment: The var xTask = Method().ConfigureAwait(false) returns immediately assigning a waitable task to xTask. The method is executing in the background untill we reach the "await". If the task has finished then you get the result, if not it waits until the task is complete. ConfigureAwait(false) specifies that once the await returns it doesn't have to return on the calling thread, this is "best-practice" when writing/using async code in a library/api that is not accessed directly by the "UI" because you're avoiding deadlocking conditions.